# L' « avion (le plus) allégé » (« leanest ») : sens, apport, comparaison avec un synonyme ?

Tags: sens, anglais, adjectifs, synonymes, comparaison-de-langues

> Les avions les plus **allégés** et les plus économiques du monde n’ont pas
>   été créés en modifiant ce qui existait déjà : ils ont été spécialement
>   conçus à partir de zéro.
>
> [ [*Bombardier — Avions commerciaux, Agitateur de marché C Series, Technologie*](http://commercialaircraft.bombardier.com/fr/cseries/technologie.html) (je souligne) ]

Dans la [version](http://commercialaircraft.bombardier.com/en/cseries/Technology.html) en langue [anglaise](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/leanest) on dit [*leanest*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/lean/591690) ; on ne sait pas s'il y a traduction dans un sens ou dans l'autre etc. [*Alléger*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/all%C3%A9ger) c'est « rendre plus [léger](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9ger), moins lourd » (*Trésor de la langue française informatisé*) et il y a différents emplois, équestre, ou maritime par exemple pour « [l]e débarrasser en partie de sa charge en diminuant le poids de sa cargaison pour lui permettre de naviguer plus rapidement ou plus sûrement [...] » (TLFi) ; en emploi pronominal il y a un emploi en aéronautique pour « se soustraire en partie à la loi de la pesanteur » (TLFi). On lui trouve [différents](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/all%C3%A9ger/2334/synonyme) [synonymes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/all%C3%A9ger), pas particulièrement évocateurs. Par ailleurs il y a le concept de [gestion](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=lean&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) allégée, minceur, sans gaspillage, au plus juste (*lean, the approach in business...*, de *production allégée, optimisée, [au plus juste](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26540367)*, c'est-à-dire le « mode de production fondé sur l’utilisation du minimum de ressources en vue de réduire le gaspillage » ([*Franceterme*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=lean%20manufacturing&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search)), ce qui pourrait cadrer avec le [contexte](http://commercialaircraft.bombardier.com/fr/cseries/environnement.html) associé au produit en question...

---

Avec en toile de fond le superlatif de langue anglaise (*leanest*) :

- Les sens d'*alléger* sont-ils compatibles avec l'idée de « conception
  à partir de zéro », et pourquoi (pas) ; dans l' *avion allégé*, est-ce un apport en qualification que cet allègement ou une périphrase servant à déterminer le nom... qu'est-ce qu'un *avion (le plus) allégé* ?
- Peut-on identifier un (autre participe passé employé comme) *adjectif* qui pourrait servir de synonyme en contexte (la caractéristique d'un avion de ligne moyen-courrier) et le comparer avec *allégé* (et avec *leanest* si l'on veut) sous un angle ou un autre (sens, connotations, emploi en vocabulaire technique/terminologie, euphonie, style) afin d'expliquer pourquoi on le trouverait objectivement meilleur ou différent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Leanest” is, imo, the perfect word in the English version, not only because it can easily (and unambiguously) be used (as it is here) in its non-pejorative “fit and trim” (en pleine forme) sense (“It’s [s/he’s]  a lean[, mean] flying [fighting] machine”), but also because one can **“be”** lean [and therefore be built lean from the ground up]  without the automatic assumption that one has “gotten” or “become” lean (which makes it fit well with the claim that the C Series wasn’t created by tweaking [making leaner] an earlier [and less lean] design).

On the other hand (and again, in my opinion), the French version’s use of “plus allégé/s” falls well short of being “le mot juste” (my apologies for, except for the preceding three words, writing this answer in English).

Granted, regarding the “non-pejorative” nature of “leanest” in this context, “allégé” is certainly no more likely than “lean” of being construed negatively when discussing an airplane or its design (as opposed, however, to other, more standard translations of “lean,” such as  “maigre” or “mince,” which might not necessarily be seen as positive descriptions of a commercial aircraft).

As it applies to the claim in French that this plane wasn’t [just] created “en modifiant ce qui existait déjà : ils ont été spécialement conçus à partir de zero,” however, it seems that, unlike “lean/est,” the word “allégé” (as I interpret the entry you cite for it), necessarily requires, in contradiction to Bombardier's claim, a pre-existing object/design that has [“simply”] been tweaked/modified to reduce its size and/or weight.

Of course, the use of the superlative (with either “leanest” or “le plus allégé”) generally implies that something else (of lesser leanness/?allégéance?) is already in existence, but I don’t think “the leanest” implies as strongly as does “le plus allégé” that some pre-existing thing less lean/?allégéant? was necessarily tweaked to become “the leanest.”

Regarding what “un avion le plus allégé” might mean (and what some other adjectives might be), the English notion of [“bare[-]bones”](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/bare%20bones) first came to mind, but describing a plane with that term would be no less potentially fear-inspiring to its English-speaking passengers than would describing it as “mince” or “maigre” be to its French-speaking ones.

However, the notions in some of the adjectival translations of “bare bones” given in the above *Reverso* link (i.e., "basique", "épuré", "réduit au strict minimum" … "réduit à la portion congrue" ) led me to the apparently archaic/rarely-used-except-in-fixed-expressions meaning of [“congru/e”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/congru) (“Qui convient exactement”), and from there, to its top-listed (per *CNRTL*) synonym:

[“convenable”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/convenable), to which I’d add the notion of “au but” =

> L’avion le plus convenable au but/à son but/à la tâche.

Comment: Thank you! I think the meaning of _allégé_ as a quality of the design (the way they were created as it says) sort of works better than to qualify an aircraft per se. That word _épuré_ is pretty interesting, there are other words which carry the stripped down idea with a notion piercing for instance, or along the lines of _slender_. The concern for what might be fear-inspiring makes sense. I guess another similar concern was against using something that's too close to _light_. In a certain way it's like _ripped_ by virtue of dropping the excess w. or making smaller, refactoring elements etc.

Comment: _Épuré_ is often used I think for the _lignes_ of a car i.e. _aux lignes épurées_, sth. Thanks.

Comment: @Qu'arrhesrententsanshune (and PapaPoule): Why not "léger"?...

Comment: @Distic "Légé" (for describing either the craft itself or its design) might very well work in French (& granted, that's the only language that matters here), but in American English, the notion of "the lightest plane" would, imo, be too closely related to all the bad memories of the widow-making fad of the 1970s & 80s of "Ultralight & Microlight Aviation" to positively describe a commercial plane. Even as a description of its design, the notion of "a light [weight] design" (containing little or no serious matter) might not appeal to many of the plane's potential [anglophone] buyers/passengers.

Comment: @Distic Sorry for the late comment. Comparing the p.p. _allégé_ and the adjective [_léger_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9ger) is interesting. Personally when I think of léger I think of sth. like _léger comme un cerf-volant_. What kind of _light_ is that, does it get caught in the wind or does it "break through" it. I guess in English if one is presented with_leanest and m..._ the garden path is set for associations with lean and mean etc and once you've been there _allégé_ won't really cut it. It's possible it appeals to sth entirely different. No clue what is associated with..

Comment: _allégé_ in France for instance. Would an F1 or Nascar car be associated with _allégé_ in relationt to _stock_ and such I don't know. Or maybe it's alcohol, or cooking. What about something along the lines of athletic, like _svelte_ ? Is that too much anthropomorphic, possibly. As I'm from Qc i.e. Fr-Can. I don't have the references from France despite me being a native speaker of the language. It creates situation like these where maybe the sentence was designed for a different audience etc. One can approach the Q. from many angles, depending on origin etc. Thanks !

Comment: Complètement par hasard j'ai trouvé l'[_allègement de régime_](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=all%C3%A8gement+de+r%C3%A9gime&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), angl. _derating_, je l'ai vu en anglais utilisé (_derated_) pour un décollage quand justement on n'ajuste pas les moteurs au maximum mais plutôt en fonction de la longueur de la piste pour réduire l'usure. Bon ce n'est pas directement relié mais j'ai vu des références à a fiabilité et à a robustesse, un _tradeoff_ p/r à la puissance. Merci !